# Place a default email address in when a custom form field is left blank

Tags: php, email

I want to place a default email address in when a custom form field is left blank. I can't get the code right. I use email address in place of the real email address.

```
<?php if(get_field('cemail')) { ?>

<?php
$email =  (get_field('cemail'));
if($email!=""){
echo 'email address' ;
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get any of the code below to work.

Comment: I'll explain: I have this form that pops open when the custom field 'cemail' which is an email address is populated. I want to place a default email in that field if the poster doesn't have or place an email address in the field (leaves it blank)

Comment: <?php if(get_field('cemail')) { ?>
<div id="cform" class="contactform hidden styleit">
<h3>Get In Touch</h3>
<p>Complete the form below to contact the poster of this listing.</p>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[formidable id=8]'); ?>
</div>

Comment: Here is my code to show the contact button. If the email field is filled out the contact button shows and if clicked it pops open the contact form. (that code shown above). So if the email is left empty I want to place a default email it the field. Maybe I need an else statement with this code? 

<?php if(get_field('cemail')) { ?>
<ul>
<li><a href="#cform" id="showform" title="Contact or request more info"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact / Request More Info</a></li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>

Comment: I've made progress... If the email is blank the text below will appear, but I still can seem to plug an email address into the blank field, which then pops open a form and populates that forms return email address.

<?php if(get_field('cemail') =="") { ?>
<h3>Please Contact</h3>
<p>text text text.</p>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like;

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];
if($email=="" || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
  $email = "default_email@email.com";

echo $email;
?>
```

Comment: In certain operating configurations $email = $_GET["email"]; will give you an error if the email field is blank because the email index will not be in the GET array.  Index does not exist error.

Comment: @JamesWiley ofcourse if get parameter doesn't exists code will be give an warning but i gave this code for sample. I guess she can modify that code for her.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to substitute a default value when the email field is blank. You can do this:

```
$email =  (isset($_GET['cemail'])) ? $_GET['cemail'] : "defaultemail@email.com";
```

Don't forget to make sure submitted values are valid email addresses and always clean your inputs if values will go into a database!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I display a default value if the field was empty?

I assume that your procedural method `get_field()` simply just returns the value of a global variable `GET` or `POST` parameter so...

This can be achieved in 1 line with something called a ternary expression, an example is displayed below.

```
<form action="/member.php" method="post">
<input name='cemail' value="<?php echo (!empty(get_field('cemail')) ? get_field('cemail') : 'default@me.com'; ?>" id="cemail">
</form>
```

We're firstly checking if the field is not empty (`!`) and then using that result inside the ternary expression to dictate what to do.

Here are some sources to help you understand further what's happening above:

[Ternary Expressions](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

[PHP Empty Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: I tried this following that PHP empty syntax format but it doesn't work.

Comment: <?php
$var =  (get_field('cemail'));
if(empty($var)){
echo 'email address' ;
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if(get_field('cemail'))
{
    $email = (get_field('cemail'));
    if(trim($email) == "")
        $email = 'default@email.com';
    }
    echo $email;
}
?>
```

Comment: You might want to ditch that `?>` after the `}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, haha! Didn't notice it actually :D